# Illegal use of ngTransclude directive in the template when using compile in directive controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using compile in my directive controller to get the first directive element and compile it and then use it for other purpose I don't want to use the linking method of my directive, is there anyway to get rid this error ?

I've reproduced the issue in this [**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/vQVa3/59/):

```
   var app = angular.module('app', []);
        app.directive('panel', function ($compile) {
            return {
                restrict: "E",
                replace: true,
                transclude: true,
                template: "<div><h1>handrouss</h1><div ng-transclude ></div></div>",
                controller: function($scope, $element) {
                    var el = $compile($element.find('div')[0])($scope); // <--- this causing the issue
                  $scope.handrouss = el.html();
                },
                link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
                }
            }
        });
        app.directive('panel1', function ($compile) {
            return {
                restrict: "E",
                replace:true,
                transclude: true,
                template:"<div ng-transclude></div>",
                link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
                    elem.children().wrap("<div>");
                }
            }
        });
```

HTML :

```
<div  data-ng-app="app">
    <panel1>
        <panel>
            <input type="text" ng-model="firstName" />{{firstName}}
        </panel>
        <input type="text" ng-model="lastname" />
    </panel
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `ng-transclude` attribute from the element before compiling in the controller.

```
    app.directive('panel', function ($compile) {
        return {
            restrict: "E",
            replace: true,
            transclude: true,
            template: "<div><h1>handrouss</h1><div ng-transclude ></div></div>",
            controller: function($scope, $element) {
              var div = $element.find('div');
              //REMOVE ng-transclude attribute
              div.removeAttr('ng-transclude');
              var el = $compile(div[0])($scope);
              $scope.handrouss = el.html();
            },
            link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            }
        }
    });
```

As the transclusion has already been done in the compile phase of the directive the `ng-transclude` directive is no longer needed when compiling in the controller.

The [DEMO on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/89n4d84j/)

Comment: you are awesome